# $\sqrt[2]{1+\sqrt[3]{1+\sqrt[4]{1+\cdots}}}\approx 1.5176001678...$

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

While on chat, an interesting limit popped out: $$\sqrt[2]{1+\sqrt[3]{1+\sqrt[4]{1+\cdots}}}\approx 1.5176001678777188...\lt\phi$$
robjohn determined its value for fifty places, and Inverse Symbolic Calculator yields nothing.

---

Is there a closed form for this nice limit?

Comment: Great question! (+1)

Comment: What closed form do you expect if the Inverter fails?

Comment: Mathematica code: `f[n_]:=Module[{k=n, s=1}, While[k>1, s=(1+s)^(1/k); k=k-1]; s]`  
Then `N[f[36],50]` gives 50 places significantly.

Comment: @Chris'ssis Why?

Comment: @Did If I answered the question I'd describe myself and I don't wanna do that, not here, not now. :-)

Comment: @Chris'ssis ?? Whatever.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen I don't have any clue yet, but ISC isn't infallible. In a quick test, it wasn't able to spot $\displaystyle \frac{\sqrt{23}+\sqrt{7}}{\pi-2},$ $\displaystyle \phi^{\pi}-e$ nor $\displaystyle 3^{e-\pi/5},$ no one particularly bad-looking. It is easy to come up with simple expressions ISC can't handle. Try it yourself!

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen ISC also fails to recognize the [nested radical constant](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=nested+radical+constant).

Answer (score 4):

Let
$$r_n := 1+\sqrt[2]{1+\sqrt[3]{1+\sqrt[4]{\ldots+\sqrt[n]{1}}}}$$
(where I've added the $1$ at the beginning because it looks nicer that way and I wanted to). Then we have that $r_1=1$ is a root of the polynomial $p_1(x) = x-1$ and that (by recursion, if you want) $r_n$ is a root of $p_n(x) = p_{n-1}(x)^n-1$.

I suggest to study this sequence of polynomials instead of your complicated sequence of nested roots.

---

**Edit:** Removed the following wrong claim (after a nice counterexample by Pink Elephants):

> Unfortunately my Galois theory is a bit rusty, and I don't have time right now to review the subject, but I think it would be pretty straightforward to show that the polynomial induce a sequence of field extensions over $\mathbb{Q}$ which have strictly increasing degree, which should imply (I think) that the limit of the sequence of the $r_n$, if it exists, is transcendental.

Comment: It is possible for a sequence $a_n$ of algebraic numbers of strictly increasing degree to converge to an algebraic number, or even a rational number. One example is $a_n:=2^{1/n}$. I have no reason to expect this behavior in this particular problem, however.

Comment: @PinkElephants Thanks for your comment, I will correct my answer.

Comment: @MatemáticosChibchas I am pretty sure my sequence of polynomials works, if that's what you're meaning.